# Passing a React.MutableRefObject to sibling elements

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-typescript, use-ref

I'm sure I'm explaining this wrong but I'm trying to pass a reference to an div that may or may not be there and read that reference in a sibling component.

Let me explain, (test code in it's entirety at the end):

I define a `Overlay` component that takes a `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>` property. It then sets it's returned styled component to this ref. Though this is tricky as I'm only returning the styled div when there are items to display:

```
return (
    overlayItems.length > 0 
        ? (
            <StyledOverlay ref={ref}>
                {overlayItems && overlayItems.map(i => <p>{i}</p>)}
            </StyledOverlay>
        ) 
        : (
            <div></div>
        )
)
```

I then am trying to read this ref in a sibling component where I simply check if `ref.current == null` with the actual `const refVariable = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);` call in the parent component and `refVariable`being passed into both components.

However, even with items in the `overlayItems` array, `refVariable.current` is always equal to null. I'm not sure if this is a side effect of using `styled-Components` or if this is because I'm passing the reference incorrectly or something else entirely. Can anyone point out my mistake?

(Oh and to add to the matter, I'm using TypeScript)

Full code

```
import React, { createContext, FC, useCallback, useContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const RefTest = () => {
    const refVariable = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    return (
        <AppState>
            <RefReader ref={refVariable} />
            <Overlay ref={refVariable} />
        </AppState>
    )
}

type AppContextValue = {
    overlayItems: string[];
    addOverlayItem: (newItem: string) => void,
};

const AppContext = createContext<AppContextValue>(undefined!);

const AppState: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [overlayItems, setOverlayItems] = useState<string[]>([])

    const addOverlayItem = (newItem: string) => {
        setOverlayItems(prev => [...prev, newItem]);
    }

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{
            overlayItems,
            addOverlayItem,
        }} >
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

const StyledOverlay = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
`;

type RefProp = {
    ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>
}

const Overlay: FC<RefProp> = ({ ref }) => {
    const { overlayItems } = useContext(AppContext);

    return (
        overlayItems.length > 0 
            ? (
                <StyledOverlay ref={ref}>
                    {overlayItems && overlayItems.map(i => <p>{i}</p>)}
                </StyledOverlay>
            ) 
            : (
                <div></div>
            )
        
    )
}

const RefReader: FC<RefProp> = ({ ref }) => {
    const { addOverlayItem, overlayItems } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [result, setResult] = useState("");

    const add = () => {
        addOverlayItem(`${overlayItems.length + 1} - an item`)
    }

    const check = () => {
        setResult(`the ref current has a current reference: ${!!ref.current}`);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{result}</p>
            <button onClick={add} >Add Overlay Item</button>
            <button onClick={check} >Check Ref Current</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to this ended up being to wrap the two sub components with `React.forwardRef()`. This caused some havoc with TypeScript trying to understand the reference though and I had to force the type

```
const RefReader = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, {}>((_, ref) => {
    const { addOverlayItem, overlayItems } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [result, setResult] = useState("");

    const add = () => {
        addOverlayItem(`${overlayItems.length + 1} - an item`)
    }

    const check = () => {
        setResult(`the ref current has a current reference: ${!!(ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>)?.current}`);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{result}</p>
            <button onClick={add} >Add Overlay Item</button>
            <button onClick={check} >Check Ref Current</button>
        </div>
    );
});
```